# How To Get Application Context After Force closed

Tags: android

I integrated c2dm in my application its working fine. once c2dm
notification came i do some database operation so i need the context
to create OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper object.

OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper lDatabaseHelper =
OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context.getApplicationContext());

This is fine in normal cases.

Suppose if i force stop my application manually from settings-

> application->manageapplication. if any c2dm message came after i am
>   unable to create OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper object. it seems application
>   context getting null.

Exception :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find OpenHelperClass
because none of its generic parameters extends
OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper: null

How do i get the application context after force stopping the
application.

i tried all cases: **context.getApplicationContext() , context, this**.

Please help me .

Answer (score 2):

It might solve your problem if you explicitly tell OrmLite the name of your databasehelper class.

To do this, open res/values/strings.xml, and add

```
<string name="open_helper_classname">your.full.package.name.DatabaseHelper</string>
```

( http://ormlite.com/docs/android paragraph 5)

Answer (score 0):

force the application to take a snapshot of its current state before close and reload the snapshot on loadup. You can even configure a dialogue box to select to not open up the snapshot.

-Panda

Comment: Thanks panda,

I am new android can you tell how to do it. or sample code might helpful.